# confirmation email not sent after registration in FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, email-confirmation

My project is based on symfony 2.3.19 + lastest version version FOSUserBundle.

Actually, FOSuserBundle is working perfectly. In fact, all functionnalities are working correctly. Now, my goal is to activate the email confirmation when a user registers. For that, I configured my project in this way:

```
# app/config.yml

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Minn\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: minn_user_registration    
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true 
            template:   MinnUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig        
            from_email: 
                address: XXXXXXX@gmail.com
                sender_name: XXXXXXX  
    service:
        mailer:  fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
```

Checking this configuration, I get forwarded to `/register/check-email` with the message I wrote in `MinnUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig`. But no email was sent & no error was returned by symfony.

It there any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: do you receive others emails from your sf2 project ? if no, may be you have an smtp issue. In that case, you should use a third part smtp such as mailjet or mailchimp ... they provide free account. it's great to ensure that message are really sent

Comment: another thing, you didn't defined a port number for swift_mailer. so by default, symfony will consider port 25 for swift_mailer which is usually blocked for safety / spam issues. you should specify port 585 instead

Comment: I will check that and I will be back... Thanks

Comment: It was just an error on SMPT credentials....

Thanks again....

Comment: Please mark the question as answered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just an error on SMTP credentials.... Thanks again....